# If denying crawlers access to a directory via robots.txt, will it still index a file in that directory if I direct link?

Tags: robots.txt

I am denying indexing to a folder called `pdf` via `robots.txt`. However, I do direct link to a few files that exist in that directory.

Will search engines such as Google index those files, or ignore them because they reside in the `pdf` folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: No.

Crawlers are disallowed from indexing anything under the URL prefix you put in robots.txt.

Longer answer: It depends.

The `Allow` keyword is not part of the standard but some robots will follow it.  You can use this to [Allow a particular URL and Disallow the entire subtree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robots.txt#Allow_directive) that contains that URL.  Most bots work on a first-match-wins basis.  Google and Bing work on a longest-string-wins basis regardless of the order of the `Allow` and `Disallow` lines.